# Rails 3.2: Pass "has_one" association object to the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Query model:

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :test
end
```

which is related to a Test model:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :query
end
```

I would like to display all of the queries in a list along with the Test description that they are associated to. I've put the following into my Query controller file for the index method:

```
Query.includes(:test).each do |query|
end
```

My questions are two-fold:

1. Is the above correct?
2. What code can I use in the "view" field of my my index.html.erb file in order to display the description of the test that is associated with the Query? If I write

   ```
   <td><%= query.test.description %></td>
   ```

I get the following error: "undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop shouldn't be inside your controller. Your Queries controller should just contain the following:

```
def index
  @queries = Query.includes(:test).all
end
```

and your queries/index view should contain the loop:

```erb
<table>
<% @queries.each do |query| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= query.test.description %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

You should further refractor this by using partials and Rail's built-in support for rendering collections:

#### app/views/queries/index.html.erb:

```erb
<table><%= render @queries %></table>
```

#### app/views/queries/_query.html.erb:

```erb
<tr><%= render query.test %></tr>
```

#### app/views/tests/_test.html.erb:

```erb
<td><%= test.description %></td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work... I get the same error: undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I wonder if my db is hosed... I have the following code in my schema: add_index "queries", ["tests_id"], :name => "index_queries_on_tests_id"

Comment: FYI, One of my models was named "Tests" instead of "Test". After renaming the model, this worked! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Query.where(:test_id => params[:test_id]).all.each...
2. If you have query.test == nil, it will be error. Try <%= query.test.try :description %>